# Hex multiplication on an Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I've been coding in high-level, dynamically-typed languages for a long time, but I've just recently started working with C++ (on Arduinos). I'm trying to write a function that converts 3 `int`s between `0` and `0xFF` (RGB color values) to a single `unsigned long` that would go up to `0xFFFFFF`. Unsigned longs can go up to `0xFFFFFFFF`, so that should work.

I wrote up the following test on my personal computer and compiled it with `g++`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned long red   = 0xff * 0x10000;
    unsigned long green = 0xff * 0x100;
    unsigned long blue  = 0xff;
    unsigned long color = red + green + blue;

    cout << hex << red   << "\n";
    cout << hex << green << "\n";
    cout << hex << blue  << "\n";
    cout << hex << color << "\n";
}
```

The output is, as expected:

```
ff0000
ff00
ff
ffffff
```

This makes sense. However, I tried running the following on my Arduino:

```
void setup(){
    unsigned long red   = 0xff * 0x10000;
    unsigned long green = 0xff * 0x100;
    unsigned long blue  = 0xff;
    unsigned long color = red + green + blue;

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(String(red,   HEX));
    Serial.println(String(green, HEX));
    Serial.println(String(blue,  HEX));
    Serial.println(String(color, HEX));
}

void loop(){}
```

Unless I'm missing something (which is totally possible), this code is functionally identical, except it uses a different method to write its output. However, this is what it prints out:

```
ff0000
ffffff00
ff
feffff
```

Suspecting that architecture may have something to do with it, I tried running that code on a Mega 2560 and a Rainbowduino 3.0 (which is basically a Duemilanove w/ ATmega 328) with identical results on both. I also get the same result if I use a different data type, like `uint32_t`.

I really have no idea what's going on. Can anyone offer an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ constant expressions are computed at compile time. It looks like the compiler for arduino has performed the computation incorrectly, though - it treated `0xFF` as a negative, and did sign-extension on it; that is why the top byte is set to `0xFF`.

You can force the constants to be of the right type by using [type-specific suffixes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), like this:

```
unsigned long red = 0xffUL * 0x10000UL;
unsigned long green = 0xffUL * 0x100UL;
unsigned long blue = 0xffUL;
unsigned long color = red + green + blue;
```

`UL` suffix stands for `unsigned long`.

Rather than multiplying numbers by powers of two and adding up the results, you could use shifts and bitwise OR, like this:

```
unsigned long red = 0xffUL;
unsigned long green = 0xffUL;
unsigned long blue = 0xffUL;
unsigned long color = (red << 16)
                    | (green << 8)
                    | (blue << 0);
```

Zero shift above is completely unnecessary - the compiler will optimize it out. I added it for a more consistent look.

Comment: Both these solutions work perfectly. Thanks for the great explanation!